# SQL Server Analysis Services Tabular Source Schema Change

Tags: sql, ssas, tabular

I have a model created in SSDT (Visual Studio) for SQL Server Analysis Services Tabular. I deployed the model and it works fine.
How can I change the schema of some underlying tables in the model? Some of data types changed and some new columns added in SQL Server tables.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you have made changes in your underlying data source, you can go to the Table Menu -> Table Properties.

This will bring up a window that shows your table and all its columns.  There is a check box on each column.  If you have added fields, find the fields and make sure the check box is checked. When you click OK, any change in data types should be picked up.

[image]

Comment: Hi mmarie, is there a way to prevent Visual Studio from loading data after clicking OK? When I do this on large tables it could take almost an hour to finish.